# Stripe Checkout Form Error On Submit - Payment not succeeding (Next.js 13)

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, next.js13, app-router

I am trying to use the Payment Intent from stripe and all was working well up until I get to the point of the submitting the payment.

The intent is being created initially and being set to 'pending' as expected, the amount is being set in the checkout as expected too. So if you were to add additional products to the cart and view it on the stripe payments tab & the mongodb backend it reflects the changes as expected via the api/create-payment-intent route.ts file.

There are no errors in the console and is just resetting the form. I am using the Address Element & Payment Element from @stripe/react-stripe-js using it as per the documents from: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?client=next

Below is my CheckoutForm Component:

```
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useCart } from "@/hooks/use-cart";
import { FormatPrice } from "@/lib/format-price";
import {
  AddressElement,
  PaymentElement,
  useElements,
  useStripe,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

interface CheckoutFormProps {
  clientSecret: string;
  handleSetPaymentSuccess: (value: boolean) => void;
}

export const CheckoutForm: React.FC<CheckoutFormProps> = ({
  clientSecret,
  handleSetPaymentSuccess,
}) => {
  const { cartTotalAmount, clearWholeCart, handleSetPaymentIntent } = useCart();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const formattedPrice = FormatPrice(cartTotalAmount);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }
    handleSetPaymentSuccess(false);
  }, [stripe, clientSecret, handleSetPaymentSuccess]);

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    stripe
      .confirmPayment({
        elements,
        redirect: "if_required",
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (!result.error) {
          toast.success("Payment Success! ");
          clearWholeCart();
          handleSetPaymentSuccess(true);
          handleSetPaymentIntent(null);
        }
      });

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="payment-form">
      <div className="mb-6">
        <h1 className="text-2xl text-slate-900 mt-5 text-center font-semibold">
          Enter payment details to complete checkout
        </h1>
      </div>
      <h2 className="font-semibold mt-4 mb-2">Shipping Address</h2>
      <AddressElement options={{ mode: "shipping" }} />
      <h2 className="font-semibold mt-4 mb-2">Payment Information</h2>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={{ layout: "tabs" }} />
      <div className="py-4 text-center text-slate-700 text-lg font-bold">
        Total: {formattedPrice}
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <Button className="w-full" disabled={isLoading}>
          {isLoading ? "Processing..." : "Complete Order"}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And here the Checkout Client component (page) where I am rendering the Checkout form:

```
"use client";

import { useCart } from "@/hooks/use-cart";
import { StripeElementsOptions, loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { ImSpinner2 } from "react-icons/im";
import { CheckoutForm } from "./checkout-form";
import { AiOutlineCheckCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY as string
);

export const CheckoutClient = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { cartProducts, paymentIntent, handleSetPaymentIntent } = useCart();
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
  const [paymentSuccess, setPaymentSuccess] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cartProducts) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setError(false);

      fetch("/api/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          items: cartProducts,
          payment_intent_id: paymentIntent,
        }),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          if (res.status === 401) {
            return router.push("/login");
          }

          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setClientSecret(data.paymentIntent.client_secret);
          handleSetPaymentIntent(data.paymentIntent.id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(true);
          toast.error("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }
  }, [cartProducts, handleSetPaymentIntent, paymentIntent, router]);

  const options: StripeElementsOptions = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance: {
      theme: "stripe",
      labels: "floating",
    },
  };

  const handleSetPaymentSuccess = useCallback((value: boolean) => {
    setPaymentSuccess(value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      {clientSecret && cartProducts && (
        <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
          <CheckoutForm
            clientSecret={clientSecret}
            handleSetPaymentSuccess={handleSetPaymentSuccess}
          />
        </Elements>
      )}
      {isLoading && (
        <div className="text-3xl flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full gap-3">
          <h1>Loading Checkout...</h1>
          <ImSpinner2 className="animate-spin" />
        </div>
      )}
      {error && (
        <div className="text-3xl flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full text-rose-500">
          <h1>Something went wrong</h1>
        </div>
      )}

      {paymentSuccess && (
        <div className="text-3xl flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full gap-4">
          <div>
            <h1 className="flex items-center gap-2">
              Payment Success
              <span>
                <AiOutlineCheckCircle className="text-green-500" />
              </span>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Button onClick={() => router.push("/order")}>
              View your orders
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If there is any additional info you need please let me know but I am unsure where the issue lays

I have tried emulating the documentation from above and it should updated the payment in Stripe as successful and redirect to the return statement where I am declaring payment successful, also to clear the cart and provide the toast message but it just refreshes the form.

Comment: Nothing jumps out immediately. I'd recommend inspecting your code in your browser and setting a breakpoint at your `handleSubmit()` function and then stepping through your code at that point to see where the re-render happens.

Answer (score 0):

So I have it figured out!

Turns out the documentation isn't always best, but I replaced the `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` element with a `<div>` and added the `handleSubmit()` to an `onClick` on the "Complete Order" button:

```
<form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <LinkAuthenticationElement
    id="link-authentication-element"
    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
  />
  <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={paymentElementOptions} />
  <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
    <span id="button-text">
      {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
    </span>
  </button>
  {/* Show any error or success messages */}
  {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
</form>
```

This wasn't working because the `PaymentElement` and the `AddressElement` are forms, too, and were nested inside another form, so the `handleSubmit` didn't work as expected.